Reinstall Ubuntu 24.04 non-destructively on broken 22.04 system with dual boot
It's been a bad day. This morning I attempted to upgrade from 22.04 LTS to 24.04.01. It didn't go well. My machine is a Lenovo ThinkBook 13s G2 13.3" WUXGA, with 512Gb SSD. It dual boots Windows and Ubuntu 22.04.
I assume because of flakey wifi, the upgrade process aborted with the message:
⋮
Could not download the upgrades 

The upgrade has aborted. Please check your Internet connection or 
installation media and try again. 

Failed to fetch 
http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/curl/libcurl4t64_8.5.0-2ubuntu10.3_i386.deb 
Temporary failure resolving ‘gb.archive.ubuntu.com’ 
Failed to fetch 
http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libg/libgphoto2/libgphoto2-6t64_2.5.31-2.1build2_i386.deb 
Temporary failure resolving ‘gb.archive.ubuntu.com’ 
Failed to fetch 
http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/poppler/libpoppler-glib8t64_24.02.0-1ubuntu9.1_i386.deb 
Temporary failure resolving ‘gb.archive.ubuntu.com’ 

Restoring original system state

Aborting
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree... Done 
Reading state information... Done

However the process worked (it was hours ago and my brain is addled), I rebooted the machine - and I can no longer boot to Ubuntu, of course. If I try, I get this screen:

I can see the file system, but have no idea how to get from there to a position to re-start the upgrade process.
I have been able to boot the machine to a live USB running 24.04.01. I had hoped I could install (at least) simply to where 22.04 lives, but I cannot work out how to do that, either. I see this for the "Manual install" option:

I was hoping to install non-destructively ("unclean", I think I've seen this referred to) to where 22.04 lives ... but can't work out the options to make that work, nor even with the format checkmark enabled to do it "destructively" and ensure that the dual boot still works.
The installer gives me the option of installing 24.04 "alongside" BOTH Windows AND 22.04, and I've been considering this, as at least it would retain the current 22.04 partition. (I do have crucial data backed up from that partition, so it is not a deal-breaker to have to format it. Would be nice not to, of course.)
The headache is growing, and I'm not sure how to proceed. I would be grateful for any pointers, and will happily add any info needed given the instructions to do so.

Two different problems, seemingly unrelated: The first is a network problem (can't find the servers). So it's unclear how "the process worked". The second is a disk or filesystem error. Might be coincidence, might be a hardware fault, might something else. Backup all your data in case it's a hardware fault.

Click on the Ubuntu 22.04.05 partition, click on change, and choose it to be /, (i.e. the root partition).
If you want to install non-destructively, then proceed without checking the format option.
If you want to format the partition, then click on the checkmark and proceed.

Thanks - I tried that (in fact), but the check mark will not clear, cannot be cleared! Is this "new"? Or is there something else I should know?

Can you "change" the partition?

Yes, but I can't then clear the "check" for Format. :/ I think I'm heading towards the nuclear option... I do have data backed up.
